# Include nested HttpPostedFileBase in jQuery AJAX request

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have this view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase UploadedFile { get; set; }

    // lots of cool properties
}

public class AnotherViewModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public decimal Worth { get; set; }
}
```

I have a controller method that accepts it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyMethod(MyViewModel input, AnotherViewModel secondInput)
{
    // do stuff with input
}
```

On the frontend, I have a form:

```
<form id="photoUploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
    <label for="Image">Image</label>
    <input type="file" class="file" accept="image/jpeg" name="Photo">

    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Name">

    <label for="Description">Description</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Description">

    <label for="Worth">Worth</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Worth">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And some jQuery magic:

```
$('#photoUploadForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    e.preventDefault();

    var input = {
        Name: // get Name from form
        UploadedFile: //what do I do here?
    }

    var secondInput = {
        Description: // get data from form
        Worth: // get data from form
    }

    var uploadData = {
        input: input,
        secondInput: secondInput
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/MyMethod',
        type: 'POST',
        data: uploadData,
        success: function (data) { console.log(data); }
    });
});
```

How do I include this file and associated input data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should amend your jQuery code to send `FormData` object to your C# controller. Try this:

```
$('#photoUploadForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    e.preventDefault();

    var uploadData = new FormData();
    uploadData.append('Name', $('input[name="Name"]'));
    uploadData.append('UploadedFile', $('input[name="Photo"]'));
    uploadData.append('Description', $('input[name="Description"]'));
    uploadData.append('Worth', $('input[name="Worth"]'));

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/MyMethod',
        type: 'POST',
        data: uploadData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) { 
            console.log(data); 
        }
    });
});
```

The data sent in the request will then be bound to the ViewModel you defined.

Note that if you changed the `name` attribute of the `Photo` input field to `UploadedFile` (to match the property of the ViewModel) then you could pass the `FormData` directly, without needing to `append()` values manually.

```
var uploadData = new FormData($('#photoUploadForm')[0]);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your time! However, I must apologize as I made a mistake in creating this question. Your answer (rightfully) assumed only a single input parameter. However, the method takes two objects as parameters. I have tried creating a data variable that contains both form data and a normal object, but that doesn't work. If it's not too much trouble, could you help me out again?

Comment: I took your advice to change the Photo input name, and it worked right away! Plus, I now have less JavaScript code in my source file to worry about! My day is made, and it's not even lunch time yet, thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)